# Codeigniter Deleting database data from a select dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and  PHP and I'm trying to make a select form where i can remove exams from the database with submit button.

These are the lines of code i have:

view (examselect_view.php)

```
<form name='selectexam' action="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/exam/removeExam/" . $exams->exam_id; ?>" method='post'>   
   <select class="form-control">
        <?php 
        foreach($exams as $row)
        { 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->exam_id.'">'.$row->examname.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Verwijderen" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>
```

controller (Exam.php)

```
function removeExam($id) {
// uri segment 3 = index.php/exam/examName/NUMBER OF ID
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);   
$this->exam_model->removeExam($exam_id);
}
```

model (Exam_model.php)

```
function removeExam($id){
$this->db->where('exam_id', $id);
$this->db->delete('exam');
}
```

This is the error i'm getting from my view.

```
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

I know that the problem is somewhere in the form action. But I don't know how I have to change it.

Comment: `$exam_id` is undefined in controllers. Its `$id`

Comment: I'm guessing it is complaining about `$exams->exam_id;` in your form action. $exams is an array of exam objects?

Comment: You should instead pass the id via the post and capture it there. And also check if something has been posted before doing anything. If you would like to do as you do, anyone can delete by simply going to the correct url.

Comment: So for example. Send the form to /exam/removeexam/, check if something has been posted, get the id from the form, delete the exam, redirect to exam listing again.

Comment: @Saty, i've changed it now, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this right now. But something along the lines of this should work.

In your view, with the form:

```
<form name='selectexam' action="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/exam/remove/";?>" method='post'>   
   <select class="form-control" name="exam_id">
        <?php 
        foreach($exams as $row)
        { 
          echo '<option value="' . $row->exam_id . '">' . $row->examname . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Verwijderen" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>
```

In your controller:

```
function remove() {

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $exam_id = $_POST['exam_id'];   
        $this->exam_model->removeExam($exam_id);

        redirect('/exam/');
    }
}
```

As a general rule, never make destructive changes based solely on URL. Site indexing robots (for example google) can then accidently delete all your exams if you're not careful.

Comment: Don't forget to add `name="exam_id"` to the `select`-element, or it won't be posted. Currently, the form doesn't actually post any data.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for checking. Might have rushed the answer a bit.

Comment: Ingen orsak. :-)

Comment: Great! Welcome to Stack Overflow @user1992

Comment: @user1992 For added error reporting I like to check if the model returned an error in the controller and display an error to the user if it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with `<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/exam/removeExam/" . $exams->exam_id; ?>` may be your `$exams` is array not an object.